# "Due facce della stessa medaglia": che figura retorica è?

Tags: idioms, figures-of-speech

Dall'alto della mia ignoranza ho detto a un mio amico che 'due facce della stessa medaglia' è un 'parallelo contrapposto'. Ciò perché non sapevo come altro dire.

Allora, sicuro che sia una figura retorica, chiedo: come si chiama questa cui mi sto riferendo?

Comment: Il significato è che, per quanto possano sembrare uno l'opposto dell'altro, in realtà sono la stessa cosa.

Answer (score 8):

È una metafora (stai sostituendo un termine con un altro, sovrapponendo il significato di quest'ultimo a quello del termine originario).

Nota che, se avessi detto "sono come due facce della stessa medaglia", questa sarebbe una similitudine.

Comment: Come si chiama questa metafora in particolare? O un nome non ha?

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis una metafora è una figura retorica, non credo che ci sia una definizione per questa specifica metafora.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis mi spiego meglio: la metafora fa già parte della famiglia delle figure retoriche, non credo ci sia un ulteriore livello di definizione per altri casi specifici.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Le metafore sono figure retoriche e non credo vi sia un modo/nome più specifico per definirle. Vi è, invece, una figura retorica, simile alle metafore, più particolare: l'allegoria. L'allegoria, esprime un qualcosa in modo molto simile a come viene normalmente fatto attraverso una metafora, ma richiede una interpretazione più profonda, acuta e razionale. In letteratura e in poesia ne esistono numerosi esempi.